# Is .jar file protected by reading/editing?

Tags: java, security, file, jar

I am currently creating some little Framed application in java.

When we clean an built a main project with netbeans (therefore creating a jar file), does it create a secured jar file ?

What I mean is that mine contains some tables with keys and I don't want that future users can be able to watch these key logs.
So is the code totally hiden ? In case not, how can we "protect" jar files please?

Thank you in advance for your help, please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

EDIT :  I am currently under windows 7

Comment: chmod 711? This would only allow execution for others.

Comment: are you sure that it protects the jar file on any other computer, on windows ?

Comment: I was just throwing in my two cents.  I know it would in a *nix environment.  I can look around and see about Windows.

Comment: If yes that would be an interesting proposal. I got unix too, but sadly, I need to run this program under windows. So with your idea, maybe I would only need to chmod711 it on my unix system and then make a copy on my Windows.

Comment: I think that would be the only way to try it out.  Do you know how to check permissions in Winodws? If not, here is a link - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Comment: But if I send this .jar to a friend, he can change it on his own OS right ?

Comment: I guess it is not out of the realm...only one way to find out.

Comment: And what is the way then please ?

Comment: Just test it out. Try the chmod command and download it to a few Windows computers that you can control and have admin rights and try and change the permissions.

Comment: I will in few min, also another question, but regarding linux. When you are SU, you are able to change the read/edit access. If we make a chmod 711 on one computer, you will be able to change rigth access  with SU on another computer right ?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you.  I feel like that is out of my knowledge unfortunately.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't at all protected. It's just an archive (built on ZIP) of `.class` -es and other resources, metadata, etc.

You could try and obfuscate java bytecode with tools like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). That would give you some protection, that is - it would make reverse-engineering more difficult.

Comment: To be precise it is a zip file archive.

Comment: Of course, even the best obfuscation can't save you if you store your secrets somewhere the user can access it. More pragmatically, if it's stored in the JAR it's either plain text (and thus easily found) or encrypted, but in the latter case your code needs to decrypt it, which requires naming the algorithm and encryption key *somewhere*.

Comment: @ iccthedral : So if I understand you well, editing my Jar file with Proguard will secure it at least a little bit. Users won't be able to check the source code, or at least it will be harder for them to do it, right ?

Comment: Right, but if someone really,really wants to rev-engineer your app, he will eventually do it.

Comment: @ delnan  : I see your point. even if we use some encrypted file, the jar file include the code for decrypting them, so it's the same problem.

Comment: @ iccthedral : I didn't thought about the problem. I am actually encrypting files with my little software thanks to some keys available in a table of content. This means it is quite useless since everybody can see how I encrypt them, right ? :/ damn it ...

Comment: Read the answer given by theglauber. It isn't that bad ;)

Comment: @ iccthedral : Proguard seems easy to use at first sight. To you think the protection given can last 3 hours for a "normal" java programmer ? Since I can update regularly these keyslogs and tables and create new jars daily for example.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to encrypt the files that have the sensitive information, before you jar them. Let the application decrypt them when it needs to use the data. Use a ramdom-looking encryption key so people will be unlikely to figure it out by listing the strings in your class files.

Comment: This will not be enough.  Plenty of decompilers for Java exist.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing will provide complete protection. Storing the password outside the application may provide additional protection. Perhaps tying the decryption to something in the hardware could help (but has downsides too). But that would still be my suggestion, provided the user understands the tradeoffs.

Comment: My question is how to do it ? You suggest me to create an encrypted file in which it contains some important values (namely my key tables here), and then to decrypt it thanks to some special classes during the jar run ?

Comment: The decryption wouldn't be automatic. You'd have to write Java code to handle it (and probably would also have to write an utility tool in Java to encrypt the files). Search Google for a tutorial on Java Cryptography, or look for a Java programming book that includes cryptography. It's not trivial, but not hopelessly difficult either.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not prohibit someone from viewing the contents of the jar file there are mechanisms that provide tamper evidence and prohibit someone from creating an additional jar that appends methods to your package.

This is called [signing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) and [sealing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html).